# SIP install - unable to open siplib.sbf

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install SIP on my computer so I can proceed to get PyQt. I put the install files in a folder on my desktop ('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\Sip\sip-4.15.5'). So, to install it, I ran the following commands from CMD:

```
cd C:\Python33
python "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\Sip\sip-4.15.5\configure.py"
```

The version of python in 'C:\Python33' IS the one used in the command 'python'. Here's the output I got:

```
This is SIP 4.15.5 for Python 3.3.5 on win32.
The SIP code generator will be installed in C:\Python33.
The sip module will be installed in C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.h header file will be installed in C:\Python33\include.
The default directory to install .sip files in is C:\Python33\sip.
The platform/compiler configuration is win32-msvc2010.
Creating siplib\sip.h...
Creating siplib\siplib.c...
Creating siplib\siplib.sbf...
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile...
Error: Unable to open
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\Sip\sip-4.15.5\siplib\siplib.sbf"
```

Now, the key lines are obviously the last two, so I looked in the appropriate folder and found that there was a rather good reason for the error: there is no "siplib.sbf." The closest it gets is "siplib.sbf.in". What on earth is going on? If this is a stupid question, please feel free to tell me so.

Comment: Perhaps you're unaware of the [binary installers](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download).

Comment: @eryksun I'm not unaware of them, but as I'm having trouble importing the module I thought I might give a manual install a try.

Comment: Did you install the right architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) for your Python installation? Barring that, try [this installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must change current working directory to the sip-4.15.5 first:

```
cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming\Sip\sip-4.15.5
python configure.py
```